# Making an object from two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of objects:

```
const headers = [
  {
    ID: "1",
    Header: "General",
  },
  {
    ID: "2",
    Header: "Misc",
  },
  ...
]

const terms = [
  {
    Header: "General",
    Term: "Lorem ipsum",
    Definition: "Lorem ipsum",
  },      
  {
    Header: "General",
    Term: "Lorem ipsum",
    Definition: "Lorem ipsum",
  },
  {
    Header: "Misc",
    Term: "Lorem ipsum",
    Definition: "Lorem ipsum",
  },
  {
    Header: "General",
    Term: "Lorem ipsum",
    Definition: "Lorem ipsum",
  },
  {
    Header: "General",
    Term: "Lorem ipsum",
    Definition: "Lorem ipsum",
  },
  {
    Header: "General",
    Term: "Lorem ipsum",
    Definition: "Lorem ipsum",
  },
  ...
]
```

And I would like to have one object that has each header as a key and with an array of all the terms as the values:

```
{
  "General: [
    {
      Term: "Lorem ipsum",
      Definition: "Lorem ipsum",
    }
    {
      Term: "Lorem ipsum",
      Definition: "Lorem ipsum",
    },
    ...
  ],
  "Misc": [
    {
      Term: "Lorem ipsum",
      Definition: "Lorem ipsum",
    },
    {
      Term: "Lorem ipsum",
      Definition: "Lorem ipsum",
    },
    {
      Term: "Lorem ipsum",
      Definition: "Lorem ipsum",
    },
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

I'm guessing that there is a way to do it with .map .foreach .filter or some combination, but have been hitting a wall all day. Including just trying to put the problem into words of what I am trying to do here so I can find better search results. Any help would appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to get your result. This would only have to loop through your arrays once, instead of looping through `terms` twice, as would happen with nested `forEach` loops.

```
const obj = headers.reduce((a, o) => { a[o.Header] = []; return a; }, {});
terms.forEach(({ Header, ...x }) => obj[Header].push(x));
```

Explanation: The `reduce` converts from an array to an object. Then the `forEach` loops through and adds the terms to the newly created object.

Here's a working example:

```js
const headers = [
  {
    ID: '1',
    Header: 'General',
  },
  {
    ID: '2',
    Header: 'Misc',
  },
];

const terms = [
  {
    Header: 'General',
    Term: 'Lorem ipsum',
    Definition: 'Lorem ipsum',
  },
  {
    Header: 'General',
    Term: 'Lorem ipsum',
    Definition: 'Lorem ipsum',
  },
  {
    Header: 'Misc',
    Term: 'Lorem ipsum',
    Definition: 'Lorem ipsum',
  },
  {
    Header: 'General',
    Term: 'Lorem ipsum',
    Definition: 'Lorem ipsum',
  },
  {
    Header: 'General',
    Term: 'Lorem ipsum',
    Definition: 'Lorem ipsum',
  },
  {
    Header: 'General',
    Term: 'Lorem ipsum',
    Definition: 'Lorem ipsum',
  },
];

const obj = headers.reduce((a, o) => { a[o.Header] = []; return a; }, {});
terms.forEach(({ Header, ...x }) => obj[Header].push(x));
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic way to do it if you're not needing additional properties would be:

```
const outputObj = {}
headers.forEach(header => {
    const headerArr = outputObj[header.Header] = [];
    terms.forEach(term => {
        const {Header, Term, Definition} = term;
        if (Header === header.Header) {
            headerArr.push({Term, Definition});
        }
    })
})
```

This would loop through each header and add the Header property as a key with an empty array, then the second loop would go through the terms and add just the Term and Definition (omitting the Header).

Comment: I'm not seeing where you're filtering `terms` by `Header`...are you missing a `filter` or an `if` statement in your nested `forEach`? It looks like "General" and "Misc" will both contain all the terms, not just the ones with a matching `Header`.

Comment: @David784 - Good point. Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) here as:

```
const dict = {};
headers.forEach(({ Header }) => (dict[Header] = []));
terms.forEach(({ Header, ...rest }) => dict[Header].push(rest));
console.log(dict);
```

```js
const headers = [
  {
    ID: "1",
    Header: "General",
  },
  {
    ID: "2",
    Header: "Misc",
  },
];

const terms = [
  {
    Header: "General",
    Term: "Lorem ipsum",
    Definition: "Lorem ipsum",
  },
  {
    Header: "General",
    Term: "Lorem ipsum",
    Definition: "Lorem ipsum",
  },
  {
    Header: "Misc",
    Term: "Lorem ipsum",
    Definition: "Lorem ipsum",
  },
  {
    Header: "General",
    Term: "Lorem ipsum",
    Definition: "Lorem ipsum",
  },
  {
    Header: "General",
    Term: "Lorem ipsum",
    Definition: "Lorem ipsum",
  },
  {
    Header: "General",
    Term: "Lorem ipsum",
    Definition: "Lorem ipsum",
  },
];

const dict = {};
headers.forEach(({ Header }) => (dict[Header] = []));
terms.forEach(({ Header, ...rest }) => dict[Header].push(rest));
console.log(dict);
```